# HTTP-уведомление от Яндекс не работает на Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, http, post, yandex-money

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с проблемой на Yii2. Мне необходимо отправить HTTP-уведомление в Яндекс Деньгах. Я отправляю тестовое уведомление прямо на определенный адрес, но ничего не происходит (должен создаться файл). Причем если я ввожу этот адрес в браузер, то все нормально проходит. Далее если делаю запрос со стороннего сайта, то он тоже проходит, Но HTTP-уведомление от Яндекса не идет. Я подумал может в ЯД дело, но нет, так как все нормально отправляется на другой сайт с Wordpress.

Где Yii2 может блокировать запрос, и почему именно от Яндекса?

Comment: Добрый вечер. Смотрите логи в runtime/logs, логи сервера, дебаг панель и консоль браузера.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятнее всего дело в защите от `CSRF` - `Cross-site request Forgery`, т.е. запрос от Яндекса приходит, но блокируется.

Попробуйте добавить в контроллер на который приходит запрос:

```
public $enableCsrfValidation = false;
```

Пример:

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public $enableCsrfValidation = false;
    // тут ваши Action
}
```

Так же можно выключить `CsrfValidation` для конкретного `action`:

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function beforeAction($action)
    {
        // Если $action->id в массиве ['yandex'], yandex - это пример
        if (in_array($action->id, ['yandex'])) {
            // отключаем защиту от CSRF
            $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
        }
        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }
}
```